# Zend_Date, ISO_8601, date parsing and local system clock

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-date

I have a strange problem with Zend_Date object.

It seems that setters perform different operations with different system clock dates.
Let's assume that system date is 28 January 2013, following code:

```
$now=new Zend_Date(Zend_Date::ISO_8601);
$now->now();
echo '<br/>now: ' . $now->toString();
echo '<br/>now->day: ' . $now->get(Zend_Date::DAY);
echo '<br/>now->month: ' . $now->get(Zend_Date::MONTH);
echo '<br/>now->year: ' . $now->get(Zend_Date::YEAR);
$end=new Zend_Date('2013-02-25 14:23:34', Zend_Date::ISO_8601);
echo '<br/>end: ' . $end->toString();
$end->setHour('23')->setMinute('59')->setSecond('59')->setDay($now->get(Zend_Date::DAY))->setMonth($now->get(Zend_Date::MONTH))->setYear($now->get(Zend_Date::YEAR));
echo '<br/>endAfterSetters: ' . $end->toString();
```

will produce following output:

```
now: 28-01-2013 14:04:28
now->day: 28
now->month: 01
now->year: 2013
end: 25-02-2013 14:23:34
endAfterSetters: 28-01-2013 23:59:59
```

But if you change system clock to 29 January 2013, output is different from expectations:

```
now: 29-01-2013 14:07:22
now->day: 29
now->month: 01
now->year: 2013
end: 25-02-2013 14:23:34
endAfterSetters: 01-01-2013 23:59:59
```

Last output is **01-01**-2013 23:59:59, but should be **29-01**-2013 23:59:59 !

It happens on PHP 5.3.2 and 5.3.16, Zend_Framework 10.7, latest Zend_Date 24880 version.

Everyting worked fine in the past.

Any ideas why it happens?

P.S.: I have also found jquery datatime plugin malfunciton while using it at 29,30,31 January... But i will describe it in other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that your setters are called in sequence. So when you call `setDay(29)` you're telling it to change the date to *29th February 2013*, which isn't a valid date, so it's rolling that over to make it *1st March 2013*. Then you call `setMonth(1)`, which changes the month to January, giving you *1st January 2013*.

You can control this behaviour by passing the extend_month option to the `Zend_Date` constructor, see: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.overview.html#zend.date.options.extendmonth

Comment: That is true. Setters sequence was the problem. Reordering to  setMonth($m)->setDay($d) solved it. Thank you!